# Бесконечный цикл с отложенными сообщениями в Вконтакте

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, python-3.5

Добрый день!
Парсю xml и вытягиваю расписание из нее. Затем беру данные и отправляю в отложенные публикации в свою группу Вконтакте.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import vk
import time
from socialpost import API
import datetime

wait = 60 * 60


def vkpost():
    session = vk.AuthSession(scope='offline,wall,groups,messages', 
    app_id='123', user_login='@mail.ru',
                         user_password='123456')
    api = vk.API(session, v='5.73')

    count = 1
    flights = API()
    while count < 25:
        vol = wait * count
        times = (time.time() + vol)
        time.sleep(1)     
        print(flights[count]['from_name'])
        print(flights[count]['to_name'])

        api.wall.post(owner_id='-123456789', from_group='1',
                      message=(flights[count]['from_name'] + ' - ' + 
                               flights[count]['to_name'].),
                      publish_date=int(times))
        count += 1

    return api.wall.post


vkpost()
```

Чтобы публикция запускалась по расписанию использую следующий скрипт

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import schedule
import time
from vkpost import vkpost


def job():
    fly = vkpost()
    print(fly)


schedule.every().day.at("12:25").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Скрипт работает на openshift. До недавнего времени все работало как часы. Скрипт запускался, отрабатывал и ждал сутки следующего запуска. Сейчас, после того как VK потребовал явно указывать версию используемой api, расписание не работает. Скрипт запускается сразу же и начинает работать постоянно с интервалом в 2-5 минут бесконечно пока я его принудительно не завершу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как решить?

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблему решил вроде как. Я работал на своей машине с питоном 3.6.1, а на опеншифте уже был 3.6.4. Из-за этого не хотело нормально работать. Странно конечно, что до этого работало...
Также все еще не исключаю проблем с библиотекой schedule, но пока это в тесте